# How to prove a function of ordered pairs is injective

Tags: functions

$f: (\mathbb{Z}^+{\times}\mathbb{Z}^+) \to \mathbb{Z}^+$ where $f(a,b)=2^a3^b$

How would I show that $f$ is injective?

Comment: Note that two positive integers are the same if and only if they have the same prime factorization.

Comment: A function is injective if, for any two distinct inputs, the outputs are distinct. So  you must show that given _any_ two distinct inputs, the resulting outputs are not the same. In the given problem, this follows from the fact that $2$ and $3$ are coprime. (Why?)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$. Then $2^a3^b=2^c3^d$. These numbers have the same prime factorization so $a=c$ and $b=d$. Thus shows that $(a,b)=(c,d)$, which means that $f$ is $1-1$.